# SSLError while installing opencv on raspi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi

I was trying to install OpenCV on my raspberry pi 3 and was following the tutorial:
https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/

Everything was going well until the command:

```
sudo -H pip3 install -U pip numpy
```

After I executed the above command I got the following error(last part of the error):

> request.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate','certificate verify failed')],)",)

I have been searching for a solution for 2-3 days now. Any help would be very well appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my problem is solved. In my case, my raspberry pi 3's **date and time settings** were incorrect and therefore SSL certificate error was coming.

I changed the date using the command (Time in 24hr format):

```
sudo date -s "Day Mon date hh:mm:ss Timezone Year"
```

e.g for IST use timezone= UTC+5:30

```
sudo date -s "Thu Aug 9 21:31:26 UTC+5:30 2019"
```